# Indent's disappearing after save in VS Code?

Tags: html

New to HMTL and whenever I try to indent and save, the indents disappear. There is an example below.

Before I save:

[image: Before I save]

After I save:

[image: After I save]

I've tried several formatters, and made sure that they've been enabled. What do I do?

Comment: can you share me your settings.json file of vscode ?

Answer (score 0):

Install the following extension:

1. **HTML CSS Support**
2. **HTML Snippets**
3. **Format HTML**